# Zeilberger's potential proof of Fermat's last theorem.

Tags: number-theory, ultrafinitism

Doron Zeilberger [suggested](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/real.pdf) the following potential proof for Fermat's last theorem:

> Let's define: $$W(n,a,b,c) \equiv (a^n + b^n - c^n)^2$$ I am almost sure that there exists a
>   polynomial, discoverable by computer, with positive coefficients such
>   that: $$W(n,a,b,c) = P\left(W(n,a-1,b,c), W(n,a,b-1,c), \ldots W(n -1,a,b,c), \ldots\right)$$ for $n>3$.
>
> Since $W > 0$ for $n= 3$, and $abc>0$ FLT
>   would follow.

---

$$$$

Could someone explain how / why exactly "FLT would follow"?

Moreover, why wouldn't one have to find a separate polynomial for each (unbound) $n$?

Comment: I particularly enjoy the seven words starting the second line of text. I think that's what Fermat said, when someone had asked him about the wonderful proof. :-)

Comment: I guess because he's almost sure?

Comment: I'm almost sure that the Riemann Hypothesis is true. ;)

Comment: @TimRaczkowski - The question is not whether this polynomial exists, but rather why that would prove the theorem.

Comment: Can someone clarify what is suppposed to go in the two $\dots$?

Comment: @DanBrumleve - I assumed more elements of the form $W(a- A, b- B, c - C, n- N)$, hence my second question regarding the infinite nature of such an expression.

Comment: So this guy can solve FLT but he can't program a computer?

Comment: @DanielV - "This guy" is a rather distinguished mathematician who is in fact a strong supporter of the use of computer programming in mathematics.

Comment: @DanielV: How on Earth is maths related to computer programming? Do you think Riemann had a computer?

Comment: @SylvainJulien - Lot's of things can't be proven by hand, e.g. the four color theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof is by infinite descent. Let $n,a,b,c$ be the *smallest* possible solution to $W(n,a,b,c) = 0$, where $n>3$. Since he is almost sure that there exists a polynomial, discoverable by computer, with positive coefficients such that: $$W(n,a,b,c) = P\left(W(n,a-1,b,c), W(n,a,b-1,c), \ldots W(n -1,a,b,c), \ldots\right)$$ for $n>3$. This would mean that $W(n,a,b,c) > 0$ contradicting the fact that $a,b,c$ is the *smallest* possible solution to $W(n,a,b,c) = 0$.

Comment: This answer does not make a lot of sense (at least to me), and it does not explain the use or construction of the described polynomial.

Comment: @nbubis Note that none of $W(n-1,a,b,c), W(n,a-1,b,c), W(n,a,b-1,c), W(n,a,b,c-1),...$ are zeros. Hence, if we look at a polynomial expression with positive coefficients with these terms then $W(n,a,b,c)$ would just be a sum of positive terms an hence will never be $0$.

Comment: But how do you know that they are not zero? e.g. $W(2, 3, 4,5) =0$

Comment: Also, wouldn't sch a polynomial be unique for every $n$?

Comment: @nbubis n will be larger than 2, also he assumes there is some general formula valid for all $n$ that one could prove using e.g. induction.